# I'm trying to animate an image with keydown, but it's not working

Tags: jquery

I want #character to move up, down, left, or right depending on which of the arrow keys is pressed. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
$("#gamescreen").keydown(function(key) {
  switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
    case 38:
      $("#character").animate({top: "-=10px"});
      break;
    case 40:
      $("#character").animate({top: "+=10px"});
      break;
    case 37:
      $("#character").animate({left: "-=10px"});
      break;
    case 39:
      $("#character").animate({right: "-=10px"});
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

This might not be important, but #character is actually a div that contains four images. All of the images' positions are set to absolute.

Comment: Not the issue but, did you really want to decrement for right as well? Please post a fiddle.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it? Why can't I decrement?

Comment: I think you need to animate `left` instead of `right` otherwise your character still has a `left` position and might cause the problem.

Comment: I tried it out - it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `gamescreen` div needs to have the focus in order to capture the keydown events.  You have two options I can think of:

1) Add `tabindex="1"` to the gamescreen div so that it can get the focus.

2) Instead of binding to the keydown event of the div, bind to the keydown event of the body.  See this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zFwzD/).

Comment: I tried both options, but it still doesn't seem to work. When I copy/pasted the javascript code from your demo into my code, it stopped working as well. The image I'm animating is a gif... maybe that's the reason it's not moving? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that shows your code and that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi.  I made a fork of the jsFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/NpM7F/](http://jsfiddle.net/NpM7F/).  I had to make 3 changes: 1) the `click` event was missing a closing `});`, 2) Both the `#character div` and `#cfront img` were being absolutely positioned but you were only moving the div (which doesn't move the contained img). Just absolutely position the `#character div`, 3) Tied the keydown event to the `body` instead of the `#gamescreen div`. If you want to tie it to the `#gamescreen div`, you'll need to add `tabindex="0"` and then give it the focus.  It only captures keydown events when focused.